# Phonegap 3.1 won't load external content, despite it being explicitly set

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I realise this is a common problem and has been asked many times, however I do feel that no other answers work in this instance.

I have a basic PhoneGap application that works fine in browser, on the Android simulator, on Android devices in the XCode/iOS simulator.  It does not work, however, on iOS devices.  When adding external libraries the app essentially hangs.  It doesn't crash, but tries to load it forever more, leaving a blank white screen.

I know this is a common problem, fixed by amending the config.xml to whitelist URLs, which I believe I have done, but I still get the same problem.

My config.xml has the following entry:
`<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />`

I have also tried the following:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin=".*" />
<access origin=".*" subdomains="true" />
```

All together and on their own, with no luck.  After building to iOS (`phonegap local build ios`) I have also 'prepared' all of the plugins (`cordova prepare`).

I have tried several libraries, from various CDNs such as Google CDN and jQuery CDN.  I have also tried adding an iframe with the following:

```
<iframe src="http://google.co.uk" width="250" height="500"></iframe>
```

Which gives me a blank iframe.

If I look at the build in XCode and look at the generated platform-specific config.xml files I can see the same access XML as expected.

I am using the below versions:

- Phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0
- XCode 5.0
- OSX 10.8.5
- iOS 6.1.3 (iPod Touch)
- iOS Simulator for iOS 7

Any help is much appreciated.